# Why does Facebook share callback return "success" if the user cancels?

Tags: unity, facebook

Here is the code piece I used to debug:

```
public void Share (FacebookPost post)
{
    FacebookDelegate<IShareResult> innerCallback = (result) =>
    {
        foreach (var item in result.ResultDictionary) 
        {
            Debug.Log(item.Key + " " + item.Value); 
        }
    }

    FB.ShareLink (post.linkURL, post.linkTitle, post.linkDescription, post.imageURL, innerCallback);
}
```

The callback is expected to return a "cancelled" key if user closes the share dialog without sharing, but instead it returns "posted" key with "true" value, which is exactly the same result as when user literally "posts".

And it returns no other data that can help me to decide if user actually shared or not.

So, how can i decide if user shared or cancelled?

Answer (score -1):

I never really found a documentation for , i had to debug it. By the way, stub function in UnityEditor does not return same values (result) as those on device.
Example:
 for success post Editor: {"did_complete" : true}
 for success post Device: {"posted" : true}

Are you sure you are:
1) using latest fb plugin?
2) did you debug results on the build version?
3) are your fb app id, and all other parametres setup right, and are you using test user?

Comment: This issue was faced in android build, not in editor. You cannot recreate this bug in editor. All conditions were met.